# How to extract decimal value from following

Tags: regex, perl

I have following values in a file

```
Time:       3.610 [ms] (mean)
Time:       1.805 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
```

I need the decimal value in first row 3.610 for which I amd using following regex but the regex returns value in 2nd row 1.805 instead

```
while (<FILE>) {
            if ($_ =~ /Time:\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*\S+/)      {
                    $time= $1;
                    print "\ntime: $time\n";
            }
```

Can someone please help me with this ?

Comment: I think we need to see more code. I get both time values. (after closing the while loop)

Comment: It might be printing both values but the ques is how to extract only 1st value

Comment: Oh, then add a `last;` statement after the print to break out of the while loop.

Comment: the file contains many other lines after above mentioned lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It might be printing both values but the ques is how to extract only 1st value

You didn't state that in your original question. As others have mentioned, using `last`

```
while (<FILE>) {
    if ($_ =~ /Time:\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*\S+/) {
       $time = $1;
       print "\ntime: $time\n";
       last;    #This will leave the "while" loop as soon as it find a match.
    }
}
```

You can also put all of the entries into an array, and access any one you want that way:

```
my @time_list;
while (<FILE>) {
    if ($_ =~ /Time:\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*\S+/) {
       $time = $1;
       print "\ntime: $time\n";
       push @time_list, $time;
    }
}

print "First time is $time_list[0]\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

To get only the first value, simply quit the loop (using `last;`) after printing the value.

```
while (<FILE>) {
        if ($_ =~ /Time:\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*\S+/)      {
                $time= $1;
                print "\ntime: $time\n";
                last;
        }
```

Comment: I tried for(;;) {  if ($_ =~ /Time:\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*\S+/)      {
                    $time= $1;
                    print "\ntime: $time\n"; last;
            }

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following powershell example of a universal regex.

`Time:\s*((?<![.])[0-9]*?([.][0-9]{1,})?)\s`

## Example

```
    $Matches = @()
    $String = 'Time:       3.610 [ms] (mean)
Time:       1.805 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)'
    Write-Host start with 
    write-host $String
    Write-Host
    Write-Host found
    ([regex]'Time:\s*((?<![.])[0-9]*?([.][0-9]{1,})?)\s').matches($String) | foreach {
        write-host "key at $($_.Groups[1].Index) = '$($_.Groups[1].Value)'"
        } # next match
```

## Yields

```
start with
Time:       3.610 [ms] (mean)
Time:       1.805 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)

found
key at 12 = '3.610'
key at 43 = '1.805'
```

## Summary

- `((?<![.])[0-9]*?([.][0-9]{1,})?)` returns all decimal numbers which appear after "time:" and before the space between the time and "[ms]", valid numbers must have at most once decimal point
- the logic at the end parses all the found values which match
- $matches array is populated automatically when a regex is used to match in powershell

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this pattern:

```
(?<!\)\s)Time:\s*(\d+\.\d+)
```

No need to call any other function to extract a first match or use break statements. It will just give you the first result set.

Hope it helps!

Comment: are you running this on each line ? Try it on the whole sample file once, without looping each line and apply regex on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
/Time:\s*([\d.]+).*/
```

Tested below:

```
> echo "Time:       3.610 [ms] (mean)"|perl -lne 'print $1 if(/Time:\s*([\d.]+).*/)'
3.610
> echo "Time:       1.805 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)"|perl -lne 'print $1 if(/Time:\s*([\d.]+).*/)'
1.805
>
```